# Can I use an Arduino Due as a flash drive?

Tags: shields, arduino-due, usb, sd-card

More specifically, can I use an Arduino Due to have an interface that can plug in/out of a USB port on a computer, connect it to an SD card or similar via a sd card logging shield, and have it present itself as a flash drive to the computer?

Why do I want this as opposed to a normal flash drive? I would like the Arduino to also have access to the contents of the sd card when the computer interface is not plugged in (or rather controllable via the Arduino which device has access to the card, the Arduino or the computer), without the need to remove/disconnect the cable

Comment: Possibly - you would have to implement USB mass storage mode.  And then you would have to implement a FAT filesystem when you want to access the card from a program on the due.   That is probably possible, but if you are willing to install a custom program on the PC there are simpler ways.

Comment: @ChrisStratton no easy way to pass the card access directly to the PC? (and thus let the PC format the file system as it would a flash drive)?

Comment: That's what USB mass storage does.  But you need filesystem code yourself if you want to access the contents of the result from the due.